# Python ASCII to Unicode

Tags: python, unicode, ascii

I have known how to get this  '4f60597d'  from  u'\u4f60\u597d'

```
>>> u_str= u'你好'
>>> repr(u_str).replace('\u', '')[2:-1] 
'4f60597d'
```

**But** if there are some ascii in the string ：

```
>>> u_str= u'12你好'    
>>> repr(u_str).replace('\u', '')[2:-1] 
'124f60597d'
```

This is **not** the result I want to.

I expect that I can get the output like this : `003100324f60597d`

Could you tell me?

Comment: Yeah, got that from your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `ord()` to get the integer codepoint for each character and format that instead:

```
''.join(format(ord(c), '04x') for c in u_str)
```

Demo:

```
>>> u_str = u'12你好'  
>>> ''.join(format(ord(c), '04x') for c in u_str)
'003100324f60597d'
```

or you could encode to UTF-16 (big endian) and use [`binascii.hexlify()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) on the result; this is probably the faster option:

```
from binascii import hexlify

hexlify(u_str.encode('utf-16-be'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from binascii import hexlify
>>> hexlify(u_str.encode('utf-16-be'))
'003100324f60597d'
```

The latter also handles characters outside of the BMP, requiring 4 bytes per codepoint, which would be encoded using UTF-16 surrogate pairs:

```
>>> hexlify(u'\U0001F493'.encode('utf-16-be'))
'd83ddc93'
```

Comment: it breaks if there is a Unicode codepoint from  Supplementary Multilingual Plane e.g., [`u'\U0001F493'`](http://codepoints.net/U+1F493) that requires more than 4 hex digits.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Sure, but the OP seems to want to format all codepoints to just 4 bytes. Perhaps UTF-16 should be used instead?

Comment: I've just wanted to post: `binascii.hexlify(u_str.encode('utf-16be'))` myself :)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: That's what you get for being helpful in comments. :-P Thanks!

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: interesting, codepoints.net doesn't handle non-BMP characters correctly when rendering the Python notation (see the representations section, click on the *show more* button) but got it correct for C..

Comment: We did it again: [pull/23](https://github.com/Boldewyn/Codepoints.net/pull/23)  and [pull/24](https://github.com/Boldewyn/Codepoints.net/pull/24) :)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Hehehe! Beat you again... My version is just a straight copy of the C notation, btw.